# Complex LINQ-TO-SQL solution.......or just my inexperience?

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

Learning LINQ-TO-SQL and getting on well. But now I think I'm at a "walk before you run" stage.

This LINQ-TO-SQL works:

```
var arr = (from up in db.fad_user_physician
           join u in db.fad_user on up.userID equals u.userID
           where up.physicianID.ToString() == userIdString
           select new ListOfUsersForPhysician
           {
               userID = u.userID,
               forename = u.forename,
               surname = u.surname,
               email = u.email,
               gender = u.gender,
               dobStr = u.dob.ToString()
           }).ToList();
```

I now want to incorporate a calculation into it.
The TSQL (which works) is thus:

(Note: physicianID is the only thing I have to work with, obtained from their logon details)

EDITED 17/2/16 16:03:

```
select fuf.userid,
    ((CAST(COUNT(fuf.userid)AS DECIMAL(6,2))/
    (DATEDIFF(dd,fu.dateJoined,GETDATE())*5))*100) AS 'percent'
from fad_user_physician fup
inner join fad_user fu on fu.userID = fup.userID
inner join fad_userFoods fuf on fuf.userID = fu.userID
inner join fad_food ff on ff.foodID = fuf.FoodID
where fup.physicianID = '5C46F531-FF64-4254-8072-F291627ABD3D'
AND fuf.quantityAmount >= ff.portionSize
group by fuf.userID,fu.dateJoined
```

So basically I want a list of users for a physician, with a % calculation as well.

I've googled this for many an hour, tutorials and all. But just getting bogged down in the complexity of LINQ-TO-SQL (for the newbie!)

Should I be using a LET statement?
Should I be using a LINQ-TO-SQL statement in the select part?
I tried:

```
let maxPos = DbFunctions.DiffDays(u.dateJoined, DateTime.Now)*5
let temp = (from fuf in db.fad_userFoods 
            join ff in db.fad_food on fuf.foodID equals ff.foodID 
            join fu in db.fad_user on fuf.userID equals fu.userID 
            where fuf.userID.ToString() == userIdString 
                  && fuf.quantityAmount >= ff.portionSize 
            group fuf by new {num = fuf.userID} into e 
            select new {total = e.Key.num}).Count()
```

maxpos gives me the correct value.
But temp gives me 0.

Any guidance would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not plain LINQ. You might want to add the LINQ-TO-SQL tag and even one for TSQL. And the SQL schema. And reformat the long lines.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Tags added. Thanks to juharr for re-formatting my code

Comment: Where are your relationships? If you have added proper foreign keys, you will get relationships when your drag and drop the tables to your dbmx file.   You can then inner join a table by "from t in table2 select new { t.table1.someproperty }"

Comment: Anyways, you will find the solution to your problem in the linq select new statement. In there, you can do the calculations for each record and add them as seperate properties to your (in-memory) collection.

Comment: You're not grouping by userId and dateJoined in the `temp` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do the following using navigation properties

```
var results = from fu in db.fad_user
              from fuf in fu.fad_userFoods
              from ff in fuf.fad_foods
              where fuf.userId = someGuid && fuf.quantityAmount >= ff.portionSize
              group fu.userid by new {fuf.userID, fu.dateJoined} into g
              select new 
              {
                  g.Key.userid,
                  Percent = 100 * ((decimal)(g.Count()) 
                            / (DbFunctions.DiffDays(g.Key.dateJoined, DateTime.Now) * 5))
              };
```

or using `join` if you don't have navigation properties

```
var results = from fu in db.fad_user 
              join fuf in db.fad_userFoods on fuf.userID equals fu.userID 
              join ff in db.fad_food on fuf.foodID equals ff.foodID 
              where fuf.userId = someGuid && fuf.quantityAmount >= ff.portionSize
              group fu.userid by new {fuf.userID, fu.dateJoined} into g
              select new 
              {
                  g.Key.userid,
                  Percent = 100 * ((decimal)(g.Count())
                            / (DbFunctions.DiffDays(g.Key.dateJoined, DateTime.Now) * 5))
              };
```